# Image Name from foreach look

Tags: loops, foreach, gallery, title

I use this part of code to display images from folder . Question is how to modify this to get name of the file as the title.

```
<div id="tab1p" class="tab active">
                         <ul id="photoslist" class="photo_gallery_13">
                             <?php
                             $dirname = "images/kitchens/";
                             $images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
                             $ignore = Array(".", "..");
                             foreach($images as $curimg){
                             if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {};

                             ?>
                            <li><a rel="gallery-3" href="<?php echo "$curimg"?>" title="<?php echo "$curimg"?>" class="swipebox"><img src="<?php echo "$curimg"?>" alt="image"/></a></li>
                             <?php   }
                             ?>

                           <div class="clearleft"></div>
                          </ul>   
                      </div>
```

Kind Regards

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not properly but it works.

```
<div id="tab1p" class="tab active">
                         <ul id="photoslist" class="photo_gallery_12">
                             <?php
                             $dirname = "images/kitchens/doors/zurfix/";
                             $images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
                             $ignore = Array(".", "..");

                             foreach($images as $curimg){
                                 $name2 =pathinfo($curimg, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                                 if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {};

                                 ?>

                                 <li><a rel="gallery-3" href="<?php echo "$curimg"?>" title="<?php echo "$name2"?>" class="swipebox"><img src="<?php echo "$curimg"?>" alt="image"/></a></li>

                             <?php   }
                             ?>

                           <div class="clearleft"></div>
                          </ul>   
                      </div>
```